# How to get 0 or "NA" in a loop in R

Tags: r

I wrote a code in which I am reading 49 files and extracting p-value which pass a specific threshold and writing in a separate file. My input files (fn) looks like this

```
gene       geneName score  ES   pvalue    var   predict1 predict2
ENSG00089  KIZ      5.2849 0.4  1.27E-07  0.004  0.08   0.05
```

For some files no rows passes a specific threshold for which I need to output 0 or NA, but I am unable to do this and getting error. My code is below

```
zero <- 0
for(i in 1:49){
f <- read.csv(fn[i], header = TRUE)
f$fdr <- p.adjust(f$pvalue, method = "fdr")
data <- f[which(f$fdr < 0.05),]

name <- unlist(strsplit(fn[i], "-"))[2]
TissueName <- unlist(strsplit(name, "en_", fixed = TRUE))[2]
FinalTissueName <- unlist(strsplit(TissueName, ".", fixed = TRUE))[1]

if(nrow(data) > 0){
fdrV <- data$pvalue[[nrow(data)]]
d <- cbind(FinalTissueName, fdrV)
out <- rbind(out, d)
}
else{
  e <- cbind(FinalTissueName, zero)
  out <- rbind(out, e)
} 
}
```

However, I am getting an error

`Error in match.names(clabs, names(xi)) : names do not match previous names`

It's rbind error but I can't figure out how to remove it. Any leads would be much appreciated. Thankyou.

Comment: I think this would be easier and cleaner if you first read all of the CSV files into a list of dataframes and worked with that, rather than using a loop. It's also easier to help if you provide some example data: a couple of small CSV files and whatever is in `fn`.

Comment: Thankyou neilfws. I have edited my question with example data set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would approach this differently. Life will be much easier if you **first** get everything into one dataframe.

Let's assume your files are in a directory, `Documents/mydata`. Let's say file `data01.csv` looks like this:

```
gene,geneName,score,ES,pvalue,var,predict1,predict2
ENSG00089,KIZ,5.2849,0.4,1.27E-07,0.004,0.08,0.05
ENSG00089,KIZ,5.2849,0.4,1.05E-03,0.004,0.08,0.05
ENSG00089,KIZ,5.2849,0.4,1.00E-01,0.004,0.08,0.05
ENSG00089,KIZ,5.2849,0.4,1.11E-05,0.004,0.08,0.05
ENSG00089,KIZ,5.2849,0.4,1.33E-02,0.004,0.08,0.05
ENSG00089,KIZ,5.2849,0.4,1.01E-03,0.004,0.08,0.05
```

and file `data02.csv` looks like this:

```
gene,geneName,score,ES,pvalue,var,predict1,predict2
ENSG00089,KIZ,5.2849,0.4,1.00E-06,0.004,0.08,0.05
ENSG00089,KIZ,5.2849,0.4,1.02E-01,0.004,0.08,0.05
ENSG00089,KIZ,5.2849,0.4,1.55E-04,0.004,0.08,0.05
ENSG00089,KIZ,5.2849,0.4,1.62E-02,0.004,0.08,0.05
ENSG00089,KIZ,5.2849,0.4,1.99E-02,0.004,0.08,0.05
ENSG00089,KIZ,5.2849,0.4,1.08E-01,0.004,0.08,0.05
```

These are silly made-up examples based on your example, but the important thing is that the p-values differ.

Use `list.files` to get the full path and name of the files:

```
files <- list.files("Documents/mydata", full.names = TRUE, pattern = "\\.csv")

files
[1] "Documents/mydata/data01.csv" "Documents/mydata/data02.csv"
```

Read them into R using `lapply` which will create a list of dataframes, one for each file:

```
mydata <- lapply(files, read.csv)
```

And name each list element with the file name:

```
names(mydata) <- files
```

At this point I would bring in the `dplyr` package. Install if you don't have it, then:

```
library(dplyr)
```

Now we can combine the dataframes into one using `bind_rows` and add a column which links the data to its original file:

```
mydata <- bind_rows(mydata, .id = "file")
```

`mydata` looks like this:

```
                          file      gene geneName  score  ES   pvalue   var predict1 predict2
1  Documents/mydata/data01.csv ENSG00089      KIZ 5.2849 0.4 1.27e-07 0.004     0.08     0.05
2  Documents/mydata/data01.csv ENSG00089      KIZ 5.2849 0.4 1.05e-03 0.004     0.08     0.05
3  Documents/mydata/data01.csv ENSG00089      KIZ 5.2849 0.4 1.00e-01 0.004     0.08     0.05
4  Documents/mydata/data01.csv ENSG00089      KIZ 5.2849 0.4 1.11e-05 0.004     0.08     0.05
5  Documents/mydata/data01.csv ENSG00089      KIZ 5.2849 0.4 1.33e-02 0.004     0.08     0.05
6  Documents/mydata/data01.csv ENSG00089      KIZ 5.2849 0.4 1.01e-03 0.004     0.08     0.05
7  Documents/mydata/data02.csv ENSG00089      KIZ 5.2849 0.4 1.00e-06 0.004     0.08     0.05
8  Documents/mydata/data02.csv ENSG00089      KIZ 5.2849 0.4 1.02e-01 0.004     0.08     0.05
9  Documents/mydata/data02.csv ENSG00089      KIZ 5.2849 0.4 1.55e-04 0.004     0.08     0.05
10 Documents/mydata/data02.csv ENSG00089      KIZ 5.2849 0.4 1.62e-02 0.004     0.08     0.05
11 Documents/mydata/data02.csv ENSG00089      KIZ 5.2849 0.4 1.99e-02 0.004     0.08     0.05
12 Documents/mydata/data02.csv ENSG00089      KIZ 5.2849 0.4 1.08e-01 0.004     0.08     0.05
```

Now: we can `group_by` the filename to apply `p.adjust` to each set of data and add the new column using `mutate`:

```
mydata <- mydata %>% 
  group_by(file) %>% 
  mutate(fdr = p.adjust(pvalue, method = "fdr")) %>%
  ungroup()
```

And now we can flag the rows according to whether they are under the threshold or not:

```
mydata <- mydata %>% 
  mutate(pass = ifelse(fdr < 0.05, 1, 0))
```

The final data frame. You could use `mutate` again to apply the steps for creating `FinalTissueName` from the file name, if you like.

```
# A tibble: 12 x 11
   file                        gene      geneName score    ES      pvalue   var predict1 predict2         fdr  pass
   <chr>                       <chr>     <chr>    <dbl> <dbl>       <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>       <dbl> <dbl>
 1 Documents/mydata/data01.csv ENSG00089 KIZ       5.28   0.4 0.000000127 0.004     0.08     0.05 0.000000762     1
 2 Documents/mydata/data01.csv ENSG00089 KIZ       5.28   0.4 0.00105     0.004     0.08     0.05 0.00158         1
 3 Documents/mydata/data01.csv ENSG00089 KIZ       5.28   0.4 0.1         0.004     0.08     0.05 0.1             0
 4 Documents/mydata/data01.csv ENSG00089 KIZ       5.28   0.4 0.0000111   0.004     0.08     0.05 0.0000333       1
 5 Documents/mydata/data01.csv ENSG00089 KIZ       5.28   0.4 0.0133      0.004     0.08     0.05 0.0160          1
 6 Documents/mydata/data01.csv ENSG00089 KIZ       5.28   0.4 0.00101     0.004     0.08     0.05 0.00158         1
 7 Documents/mydata/data02.csv ENSG00089 KIZ       5.28   0.4 0.000001    0.004     0.08     0.05 0.000006        1
 8 Documents/mydata/data02.csv ENSG00089 KIZ       5.28   0.4 0.102       0.004     0.08     0.05 0.108           0
 9 Documents/mydata/data02.csv ENSG00089 KIZ       5.28   0.4 0.000155    0.004     0.08     0.05 0.000465        1
10 Documents/mydata/data02.csv ENSG00089 KIZ       5.28   0.4 0.0162      0.004     0.08     0.05 0.0298          1
11 Documents/mydata/data02.csv ENSG00089 KIZ       5.28   0.4 0.0199      0.004     0.08     0.05 0.0298          1
12 Documents/mydata/data02.csv ENSG00089 KIZ       5.28   0.4 0.108       0.004     0.08     0.05 0.108           0
```